# How to drag point on maps when scroll the map in react native

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us2dn.gif)i"m willing to use this feature in my app when I scroll the map the marker automatically drag like in uber and careem apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a customer marker with an image or icon and then you can use

```
   <MapView   
     ....
     onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => {
                  this.setLocation(region);}>
```

and then you can setState the updated region as you scroll.

```
 setLocation = (region) => {
try {
  if (region && region.longitude !== 0) {
    const latitude = region.latitude;
    const longitude = region.longitude;
    if (
      latitude.toFixed(6) == this.state.region.latitude.toFixed(6) &&
      longitude.toFixed(6) == this.state.region.longitude.toFixed(6)
    ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.setState({region}, () => {
        console.log('New Region', this.state.region);
      });
    }
  }
} catch {
  Alert.alert('App name', 'Location Permission not granted');
}
```

};

this might will be helpful for you.